# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Binding

Tags: datagridview

Right this is driving me nuts.
I feel like I have read every post on the web with still nothing sinking in.
All im trying to to is bind to a List

```
gvCompany.DataSource = BLL.Inventory.Company.GetAllActive(forceReload);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn stateColumn = GridViewComboBoxColumn();
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cellCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
stateColumn.DataPropertyName = "StateName";
stateColumn.CellTemplate = cellCombo;
gvCompany.Columns.Add(stateColumn);
 private static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GridViewComboBoxColumn()
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn sColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

           sColumn.DataSource = BLL.Inventory.State.GetAllActive();
           sColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
           sColumn.ValueMember = "OID";
            return sColumn;
        }
```

Can some one show me what im doing wrong?
It Binds but I dont get any drop down,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable Editing on the `DataGridView`. This should allow the Comobox Column to drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confused, this should work:

```
void initGridView()
{
    DataGridView gvCompany = new DataGridView();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn sColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    //Load Data to ComboBoxColumn
    sColumn.DataSource = BLL.Inventory.State.GetAllActive();

    sColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
    sColumn.ValueMember = "OID";
    gvCompany.Columns.Add(sColumn);

    //Load Data
    gvCompany.DataSource = BLL.Inventory.Company.GetAllActive(forceReload);
}
```

You should try a simple data source first to make sure there is no problem here, you can use a `List<String>`

You don't need to use `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` unless you want to specify diferent datasource to combobox in diferents lines.

Answer (score 0):

Trying binding to a `BindingList<T>`.  Sometimes weird behavior like you're seeing can be fixed by setting the `DataSource` to a `BindingList<T>` rather than a `List<T>`.  For example, assuming your type is called `Company`:

```
gvCompany.DataSource = new BindingList<Company>(BLL.Inventory.Company.GetAllActive(forceReload));
```